# React-rails store POST request response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

currently i used Ruby on Rails as my backend to serve API to my apps. And my front end i use React-rails gem (React.js) to get/post data and generate output. Both API and apps are on different server.

My problem here is, i cannot store response from POST request i made in react. How can i do so ? I am new in react btw.

What i want to do now is when user want to login the apps will POST request to API and get "auth_token" response. I want to store this "auth_token" response in header and access into dashboard. But i stuck now how can i store the auth_token ftw.

Below is my code for POST data :

```js
var LoginBody = React.createClass(
{
    handleClick() {
        var username  = this.refs.username.value;
        var password = this.refs.password.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/users/central/signin?',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { user_login:{email: username, password:password} },
            success: (data) => {
                 this.setState({auth_token: data.auth_token});
            }.bind(this),
        });
    },
    getInitialState(){
      return {
        auth_token: []
      }
    },
```

If there's someone that could solve my problem and teach me how can i store in header in my apps i really appreciate it.

Comment: you can store in local storage of the browser

Comment: @emaillenin how can i do so with react ? may i have some guidance from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store them in local storage like:

```
localStorage.authToken = data.auth_token
```

And then whenever you need them in your future requests, just read as:

```
localStorage.authToken
```